# Locks while stream reading and deleting/inserting involving the same tables?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, blocking

I have a question regarding a potential block/lock situation:

I am reading data using a select command, which is then modified externally and uploaded to a temporary table. A stored procedure will then use MERGE INTO in order to apply the changes to the original table. When system resources are getting short a flush happens - resulting in the data reader still being open while the SP is executed. Reading and SP executions run on their own separate connections.

Is it probable that this behavior will cause locks and therefore rather lengthy execution times (over 5 hours having around 100k entries, 5k being altered)?

This is the most relevant part of the SP:

```
[Some deletions in OrderAssociations depending on user settings]

MERGE INTO OrderAssociations a
USING #OrderAssociations b
    ON a.OrderId = b.OrderId
    AND a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT 
    (
        OrderId, 
        CustomerId,
        ShopId,
        Sequence
    )
    VALUES
    (
        b.OrderId, 
        b.CustomerId,
        b.ShopId,
        (
           SELECT 
              ISNULL(MAX(Sequence), 0) + b.Sequence 
           FROM OrderAssociations c 
           WHERE c.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
        )
    )
    OUTPUT INSERTED.CustomerId INTO @InvolvedCustomerIds;
```

The selection command is as follows:

```
SELECT 
   a.OrderNo, 
   '[Deleted by ERP]' AS PathPart1, 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 102) AS PathPart2, 
   ISNULL(lcn.Name, 'No Name') AS PathPart3
FROM OrderAssociations ca 
LEFT JOIN LocalizedCustomers lcn 
   ON ca.CustomerId = lcn.CustomerId 
INNER JOIN Orders a 
   ON a.OrderId = ca.OrderId 
WHERE ca.ShopId = '548F9654-5369-41ED-B1E9-80BB04477DBE' 
AND lcn.LanguageId = 1 
ORDER BY lcn.Name
```

Comment: Are you using the default isolation level (read committed), have you looked at snapshot isolation to minimize locking?

Comment: yes, the transaction has default isolation level. at least i am not specifying otherwise. i am more interested in the fact whether locks can occur or are probable extending the runtime length. i imagine your advise might help in that case.

Comment: Are you on SQL 2014? Prior to that the isolation level of pooled connections is essentially random. Make sure you are running under a sane level by explicitly setting it.